# Creating Win32 controls in a separate class

Tags: c++, win32gui

I have a `Window` class and a `MainMenu` class. In the `Window` class, I create the window itself, and in the `MainMenu` class I create the controls for the `Window` (like in C# with form and user-control).

Do I need to define, let's say `#define EXIT_BUTTON 1`, in `Window.cpp` and `MainMenu.cpp` for button events to work, or is there a better way?

```
exit = CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Exit", style, monitor.right / 2 - 100, 150, 200, 100, m_hWnd, **HMENU(EXIT_BUTTON)**, NULL, NULL);
```

Window.cpp

```
#include "Window.h"

#define EXIT_BUTTON 1

MainMenu* mainMenu1;

Window::Window() : m_hInst(GetModuleHandle(nullptr)) //creates the window
{
    WNDCLASS wc = {};

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = m_hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindProc;

    RegisterClass(&wc);
    
    DWORD style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE;

    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &monitor);

    m_hWnd = CreateWindow(ClassName, WindowTitle, style, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    mainMenu1 = new MainMenu(m_hWnd, monitor);

    ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
}

Window::~Window()
{
    UnregisterClass(ClassName, m_hInst);
    delete mainMenu1;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) // gets input from user
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddControls();
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp) {
        case EXIT_BUTTON:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
        std::cout << "1";
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
    return 1;
}

bool Window::ProcessMessage()
{
    MSG msg = {};
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE)) {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            return false;

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    
    return true;
}

void AddControls()
{
    mainMenu1->Initialize();
}
```

MainMenu.cpp

```
#include "MainMenu.h"

#define EXIT_BUTTON 1

MainMenu::MainMenu(HWND hWnd, RECT monitor)
{
    this->monitor = monitor;
    m_hWnd = hWnd;
}

MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{
    
}

void MainMenu::Initialize()
{
    DWORD style = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_CENTER;

    title = CreateWindow(L"static", L"Welcome", style, monitor.right / 2 - 100, 100, 200, 100, m_hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SendMessage(title, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(CreateFont(50, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET,
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, L"Arial")), true);
    exit = CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Exit", style, monitor.right / 2 - 100, 150, 200, 100, m_hWnd, HMENU(EXIT_BUTTON), NULL, NULL);
}

void MainMenu::Hide()
{
}

void MainMenu::Show()
{
}
```

Comment: Use the dialog resource editor. Then use either [`DialogBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxw) for a modal dialog or [`CreateDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogw) for a modeless dialog.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. You are making your own OOP wrapper around Win32 so you decide how you want to handle the fact that child controls have numeric IDs. There is no right or wrong answer here so it doesnt really work as a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Having a #define in multiple .cpp files is a very bad idea.  Put them in a .h file so there's only one definition and only one place to edit them.  The wizards built into VS use resource.h for such identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create app_common.h header file and write define to it.

app_common.h

```
#pragma once

#define EXIT_BUTTON 1
```

and update your Window.cpp

```
#include "app_common.h"
#include "Window.h"
....
```

and then update your MainMenu.cpp

```
#include "app_common.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
.....
```